# Why am I getting errors with npx?

Tags: npm, create-react-app, npx

everytime when I run any npx command it gives me the same error.
Except when I run: `npx -v` then it gives me the version: 9.2.0

here is the error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path E:\Development
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'E:\Development'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-02T20_03_57_627Z-debug-0.log
```

I have updated npm with nvm but that didnt make a change.

I want to run `npx create-react-app myApp` or `npx create-electron-app myApp` but every command gives me the same error.
Can somebody help me to get rid of this error ?

Comment: Seems to be an npm bug https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7089

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same problem so I just did this "mkdir %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm" and then everything worked.  Seems some sort of setup bug probably because I installed NPM from a different user account on the machine.

Comment: This solved it for me too! Thanks!

Comment: For me I still needed to do: 1) npm i npx and 2) npm i npm. Then it worked.

Answer (score 6):

Also had the same issue.

I was able to resolve it by manually navigating to the mentioned directory and creating the folder that it claimed not to be seen. (in your case "Development" and in my case "npm")

In my case:

```
C:\Users\<PC-USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming
```

Started moving from the hard drive (disk C) to the other folder. *Ensure you show hidden files.* I just created the "npm" folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the issue because your using an capital letter.
Try this `npx create-react-app my-app`

Answer (score 0):

1. create all directories it's showing doesn't exist manually. sometime packages create folder automatically but if it's not doing so use mkdir to create folder . i had same issue while using npx create-react-app pizza-menu. I was having this error :npx create-react-app pizza-menu
   npm ERR! code ENOENT
   npm ERR! syscall lstat
   npm ERR! path C:\Users\sekho\AppData\Roaming\npm
   npm ERR! errno -4058
   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\sekho\AppData\Roaming\npm'
   npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
   npm ERR! enoent

To solve this I used these steps inside your user folder:
cd AppData
cd Roaming
mkdir npm
and it worked.

2. Make sure install package.json file after deleting it once you create npm folder,sometimes it missed some configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I did `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli @react-native-community/cli` and `init` again and it just worked.